# Are infinite subsets of the real field definable by a single formula?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{R},+,*,0,1,<)$. We adjoin to it a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it possible to give a single formula $F$ in the expanded language such that $F$ is true precisely when $S$ is an infinite subset of the reals? I know it is certainly possible by replacing $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{N}$ or by $\mathbb{Z}$. We can just say that $S$ has no upper bound, in the case of $\mathbb{N}$, or that $S$ has either no upper bound or no lower bound, in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: To clarify, you're adding a unary predicate symbol to the language?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. $S$ is infinite if and only if either $S$ is unbounded or $S$ contains pairs of elements arbitrarily close together: $\forall {\epsilon>0}\,\exists x\in S\,\exists y\in S(0< (x-y)^2<\epsilon)$.

Comment: You should make clear that your formula only corresponds to the second half of your written condition.

Comment: @StigHemmer Thanks, but imo it's already pretty clear.