# Are infinite subsets of the rationals definable?

Tags: model-theory

This is really two questions in one. Consider the structure $(\mathbb{Q},<)$. We adjoin to it a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{Q}$. Is there a first-order formula $F$ in the expanded language such that $F$ is true precisely when $S$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{Q}$? If it is not definable in that language alone, is it definable in the expanded language $(+,-,*,0,1,<)$?

Comment: For the benefit of readers, here are links to your two previous closely related questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701577/are-infinite-subsets-of-the-real-field-definable-by-a-single-formula and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3706235/can-infinite-subsets-of-the-reals-be-defined-by-their-order-alone

Comment: Are we devolving, slowly, through the models? What did you try, since your last question (which, as @Alex suggets, you *really* should mention for context)?

Comment: I've edited my answer with a second proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hagen von Eitzen has answered the second question (and note that the answer is exactly the same idea as David C. Ullrich's answer to your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3701577/are-infinite-subsets-of-the-real-field-definable-by-a-single-formula)).

The answer to the first question is no. Fix an irrational number $\alpha\in \mathbb{R}$. Let $(a_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly increasing sequence of rational numbers approaching $\alpha$ from below, and let $(b_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a strictly decreasing sequence of rational numbers approaching $\alpha$ from above. Let $S = \{a_i\mid i\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{b_i\mid i\in \mathbb{N}\}$. The motivation for picking $S$ this way is that it is a discrete linear order with endpoints and with no limit point in $\mathbb{Q}$, just like every finite subset of $\mathbb{Q}$.

I claim that $S$ is indistinguishable from a finite set inside $(\mathbb{Q};<)$. More precisely, for any formula $\varphi$, there exists an $N$ such that $(\mathbb{Q};<,S)\models \varphi$ if and only if $(\mathbb{Q};<,T)\models \varphi$, where $T$ is any subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ of size $N$. This can be proven using the [Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfeucht%E2%80%93Fra%C3%AFss%C3%A9_game).

---

Here's another proof that trades out the Ehrenfeucht-Fraïssé game for Łoś's theorem and countable categoricity of $(\mathbb{Q},<)$.

Suppose for contradiction that $\varphi$ is a sentence in the language $L' = \{<,S\}$ such that $(\mathbb{Q};<,S)\models\varphi$ if and only if $S$ is infinite.

For each natural number $n$, let $Q_n = (\mathbb{Q};<,T_n)$, where $T_n$ is a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ of size $n$. So $Q_n\models \lnot \varphi$. Let $U$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$, and let $Q^\star$ be the ultraproduct $\prod_{n\in \mathbb{N}} Q_n / U$. In $Q^\star$, the interpretation of the relation symbol $S$ is infinite, but $Q^\star\models \lnot \varphi$, by Łoś's theorem.

Now let $(Q;<,S)$ be a countable elementary substructure of $Q^\star$, so again $S$ is infinite and $Q\models \lnot \varphi$. But the reduct $(Q;<)$ to the order language is a countable dense linear order without endpoints, so it is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Q};<)$. Let $f\colon Q\to \mathbb{Q}$ be the isomorphism, and let $S' = f(S) \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$, the image of $S$ under the isomorphism. Then $(Q;<,S)\cong(\mathbb{Q};<,S')$, so $(\mathbb{Q};<,S')\models \lnot \varphi$, contradicting the fact that $S'$ is infinite.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** on the second part: $S$ is infinite iff it is non-empty, and either not bounded or there exist arbitrarily close elements.

$$\exists a\colon a\in S \land (\forall a\in S\,\exists b\in S\,a<b
\lor \forall a\in S\,\exists b\in S\,b<a\\
\lor \forall d\in\Bbb Q\,d>0\to \exists a\in S\,\exists b\in S\,a<b\land b<a+d )$$